# Is there any way to get data about a query from a query object in Firebase Firestore libraries?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The title doesn't really explain this very well.

What I mean is: for example, I build a query like so (taken from firebase website):

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
Query query = citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CA");
```

Is there any way to get the queries information that I supplied above back from the query, such as the fact that it is looking for items where "state" is equal to "CA". Basically, I'm trying to get a string representation of the query that I can use in later code to see what the query was searching for. Something like:
`query.getInfo()` which would return `FIREBASE QUERY ON /cities/ WHERE state EQUALSTO CA` or even the opportunity to pick individual parts such as the 'whereEqualTo' which would return `state == CA` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no getInfo() method in the Firestore [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) class. If you need to know what your users are searching for, then you should create your own mechanism for that. The best option that you have is to store the String representation of those searches either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).